# Copy a struct to pass to a function - this field does not implement `Copy`

Tags: struct, rust, move-semantics, pass-by-value

Here is my struct:

```
#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
pub struct ArimaModel {
    p: u8,
    d: u8,
    q: u8,
    holdout_length: u16,
    max_ar_lag: u8,
    max_ma_lag: u8,
    df_lags: u8,
    time_series: Vec<f64>,
    ar_lags: Vec<usize>,
}
```

I am trying to pass my struct to multiple functions.

Here is my error:

```
error[E0204]: the trait `Copy` may not be implemented for this type
  --> src/lib.rs:1:10
   |
1  | #[derive(Copy, Clone)]
   |          ^^^^
...
10 |     time_series: Vec<f64>,
   |     --------------------- this field does not implement `Copy`
11 |     ar_lags: Vec<usize>,
   |     ------------------- this field does not implement `Copy`
```

Comment: `Vec` does not implement `Copy`. As such, you'll have to use an array or pass a reference.

Comment: _"I am trying to pass my struct to multiple functions"_ — Please could you post the code where you do that.

Comment: I found the linked question by searching for [how to implement copy for a type [rust]](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=how+to+implement+copy+for+a+type+%5Brust%5D). `String` is this way because it contains a `Vec`, so the answers apply just as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If a type implements `Copy`, ["copies happen implicitly"](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Copy.html#whats-the-difference-between-copy-and-clone), i.e. you do not have to explicitly state that you want to copy the value. Because `Vec` implements `Drop`, it can not implement `Copy`, preventing you from accidentally copying values around without noticing it.

Thus, `Vec` only implements `Clone` (if the contained type implements `Clone`), so that you can explicitly copy a vector by calling `Clone`.

Similarly, you should think twice if `ArimaModel` should really derive `Copy` or if you actually want to derive `Clone` so that you have to explicitly state that you want a copy.

But if you just want to pass `ArimaModel` into different functions, you might want to borrow them (i.e. pass `&ArimaModel` or `&mut ArimaModel` instead of  `ArimaModel`).

Comment: You can't implement copy for just any type.  It only works on things like primitives and references, and structs/enums consisting of copyable types.  Op's struct is not one of those.  Copy does a byte for byte copy of the value which won't work for something with heap allocations like `Vec`.  Op's only recourse is to clone his struct every time he passes it to a function, or preferably make his functions take a reference.  He/she could also have his struct contain something other than `Vec`s.